# programmatically transform python code via lib2to3

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'd like to transform all occurrences of "some_func(a, b)" in a Python module to "assert a == b" via Python's standard lib's lib2to3. I wrote a script that would take source as input:

```
# convert.py
# convert assert_equal(a, b) to assert a == b
from lib2to3 import refactor
refac = refactor.RefactoringTool(['fix_assert_equal'])
result = refac.refactor_string('assert_equal(123, 456)\n', 'assert equal')
print(result)
```

and the actual fixer in a separate module:

```
# fix_assert_equal.py, in same folder as convert.py
from lib2to3 import fixer_base, pygram, pytree, pgen2
import ast
import logging

grammar = pygram.python_grammar
logger = logging.getLogger("RefactoringTool")
driver = pgen2.driver.Driver(grammar, convert=pytree.convert, logger=logger)
dest_tree = driver.parse_string('assert a == b\n')


class FixAssertEqual(fixer_base.BaseFix):
    BM_compatible = True

    PATTERN = """
    power< 'assert_equal'
        trailer<
            '('
            arglist<
                obj1=any ','
                obj2=any
            >
            ')'
        >
    >
    """

    def transform(self, node, results):
        assert results
        obj1 = results["obj1"]
        obj1 = obj1.clone()
        obj1.prefix = ""
        obj2 = results["obj2"]
        obj2 = obj2.clone()
        obj2.prefix = ""
        prefix = node.prefix

        dest_tree2 = dest_tree.clone()
        node = dest_tree2.children[0].children[0].children[1]
        node.children[0] = obj1
        node.children[2] = obj2
        dest_tree2.prefix = prefix

        return dest_tree2
```

However this produces the output `assert123 ==456` instead of `assert 123 == 456`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What is your end goal here?  Are you actually trying to transform source code (e.g. re-writing it for a different purpose)?  Or do you just want to do some runtime swapping?  If the latter, why not just replace the function `assert_equal` with a function that asserts that the arguments are equal?

Comment: I want to remove dependency on some_func, which in this particular case happens to be diable by rewriting in terms of builtin assert.

Comment: This feels like a hack no matter how I think of the problem -- But why not just monkey patch `some_func` with another that simply calls `assert`?

Comment: @mgilson Not an option (coding standards).

Comment: sooo ... Monkey patching isn't allowed, but coming up with a solution where you magically re-write the source code at runtime _is_?  I'm generally not in favor of monkey patching (so I can sympathize with the writers of your standards), but I definitely don't think that re-writing the code at runtime is better in _any_ way.

Comment: @mgilson I'm with you re monkey-patchin run-time, but this is not run-time: it will be in a script that will be run once on all source files, sorry I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: the obj2.prefix should not be set to "", this removes the space before the object.